# Join table and order by PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to do a simple order by lowest to highest and highest to lowest using php to no avail.

I have no idea whats stopping it to work and I always get the mysql data `ordered by yt.id` lowest to highest for some strange reason.

this is my query code:

```
$clause = " WHERE ";//Initial clause
$sql="SELECT *
FROM `yt`
INNER JOIN `ATTRIBUTES` ON yt.id=ATTRIBUTES.id";//Query stub
    if(isset($_POST['keyword'])){

        foreach($_POST['keyword'] as $c){
            if(!empty($c)){
                $keyword2 = $_POST['keyword2'];
                ##NOPE##$sql .= $clause."`".$c."` LIKE '%{$c}%'";
                $sql .= $clause . " (ATTRIBUTES.sizes LIKE BINARY '$c' OR ATTRIBUTES.colors LIKE BINARY '$c' OR ATTRIBUTES.manu LIKE BINARY '$c' OR ATTRIBUTES.attr LIKE BINARY '$c') AND ATTRIBUTES.type='$keyword2'";
                $clause = " OR ";//Change  to OR after 1st WHERE
            }
        }
        $sql .= " GROUP BY yt.id";
        $sql .= " ORDER BY yt.id DESC";

///rest of my code/////
```

it doesn't really matter what I do, I always get lowest to highest!

am I doing this right?

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote. please do let me know the reason behind your downvote so I am more careful in the future.

Comment: could it be the "ORDER BY yt.id DESC" clause?

Comment: @RamRaider, do you mean like this: `$clause = " ORDER BY yt.id DESC";`  ? if so, I did try that and it doesn't work.

Comment: GROUP BY and ORDER BY should be the end the of the query statement so the above statement looks correct by that account. Can you try echo $sql at the end of your code to see what the final query statement looks like? Try running that query directly against the database maybe and see if you get the right results ?

Comment: the sql above includes the clause "ORDER BY yt.id DESC" - surely therefore it will always order that way?

Comment: the column id contains integer value?

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). Enjoy having your server pwn3d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you always have any `$_POST['keyword']` ?

If not or even if you have try:

```
$clause = " WHERE ";//Initial clause
$sql="SELECT *
FROM `yt`
INNER JOIN `ATTRIBUTES` ON yt.id=ATTRIBUTES.id";//Query stub
if(isset($_POST['keyword'])){

    foreach($_POST['keyword'] as $c){
        if(!empty($c)){
            $keyword2 = $_POST['keyword2'];
            ##NOPE##$sql .= $clause."`".$c."` LIKE '%{$c}%'";
            $sql .= $clause . " (ATTRIBUTES.sizes LIKE BINARY '$c' OR ATTRIBUTES.colors LIKE BINARY '$c' OR ATTRIBUTES.manu LIKE BINARY '$c' OR ATTRIBUTES.attr LIKE BINARY '$c') AND ATTRIBUTES.type='$keyword2'";
            $clause = " OR ";//Change  to OR after 1st WHERE
        }
    }
}
$sql .= " GROUP BY yt.id";
$sql .= " ORDER BY yt.id DESC";
```

Or just show us a full code fragment what happens if not or after `if(isset($_POST['keyword'])){`

Comment: OMG mate, I feel stupid now. I've been trying to edit my code that i posted in this question for ages and I only needed to look a bit down the page (my codes) and edit some stuff after my $_POST['keyword'] stuff... your first line of comment/question pin pointed the issue and now it works fine... I think i need to give my brain a rest otherwise i will make a mess of my website.lol

Comment: :-) cup of coffee with 15 min rest could save bunch of hours :-) I 100% agree with you